# Combining xmelements with constructor

Tags: java, xml, constructor, jaxb

I have a class order which has 3 fields: id, name and showing-id.
I have a xml-file with orders and reading them worked perfect.
However, I made a constructor for Order and now it doesn't work anymore.
How can I have a constructor and xml-elementbinding at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAXB requires a no-arg constructor.  You should be able to provide one (try marking it private) and things should work.

If the object isn't the root one, then you could also create an object with a default constructor and use an `XmlAdapter` to convert to/from it to avoid having to add the no-arg constructor to your domain object (see linked article below for an example).

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html